# save a structure with dynamic name in each for loop

Tags: matlab, save, structure

I have a for loop in which a structure with a dynamic name must be saved. for example

```
save SubjInfoRisk.mat   SubjInfo
```

In the second loop, I need to save

```
save SubjInfoCAD.mat  SubjInfo
```

To do so, I concatenated strings as below:

```
Group={'CAD','RISK'}
 matflename=strcat('SubjInfo',group{1},'.mat')
 save matflename  subjInfo
```

But it doesn't work. any suggestion?

Best

Comment: It's a typo: you define `Group` with capital letter and address it as `group`, non-capital. Voting to close question because of typo.

Comment: @ViG: there is a typo there, but even after fixing that it wouldn't work: you'd need to use the functional form of `save` for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
save matflename  subjInfo
```

translates to

```
save('matflename','subjInfo')
```

That is, any of the commands that don't look like function calls are actually function calls with strong arguments. So you are saving to a file called "matflename". Instead, do:

```
save(matflename,'subjInfo')
```